# Where can I download previous versions of Azure Data Studio?

Tags: azure

I always end up on [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15) but it does only propose the latest version.

I'd like these for Windows, MacOS and Linux. Are these available somewhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like these for Windows, MacOS and Linux. Are these available somewhere ?

Azure Data Studio is GitHub so you can download previous releases [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/releases).

[Azure Data Studio](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio)